# Turning DataFrameGroupBy.resample hierarchical index into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains individual observations that I need to aggregate at coarse time intervals, as a function of several indicator variables at each time interval. I assumed the solution here was to do a `groupby` operation, followed by a resample:

```
adult_resampled = adult_data.set_index('culture', drop=False).groupby(['over64','regioneast','pneumo7',
            'pneumo13','pneumo23','pneumononPCV','PENR','LEVR',
            'ERYTHR','PENS','LEVS','ERYTHS'])['culture'].resample('AS', how='count')
```

The result is an awkward-looking series with a massive hierarchical index, so perhaps this is not the right approach, but I need to then turn the hierarchical index into columns. The only way I can do that now is to hack the hierarchical index (by pulling out the index labels, which are essentially the contents of the columns I need).

[image: hack]

Any tips on what I ought to have done instead would be much appreciated!

I've tried the new `Grouper` syntax, but it does not allow me to subsequently change the hierarchical indices to data columns. Applying `unstack` to this table:

[image: Grouper]

results in this:

[image: bad unstack]

In order for this dataset to be useful, say in a regression model, I really need the index labels as indicators in columns.

Comment: See here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#grouping-with-a-grouper-specification, this gives you the ability to arbitrarily group/resample 'at once', also here: https://github.com/jreback/pydata2014-pandas (the groupby enhancements section)

Comment: @Jeff: I like the jokes in your slides :) When and where will the talk be given?

Comment: hah. was 2 weeks ago. :(. I don't think the video link is out yet. will post when it is.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. That isn't quite what I am looking for. I still end up with all of the groups in the hierarchical index. I want them to be columns (i.e. dummy variables) like I have in the hacked table above. I'm wondering if there is a good way of moving the hierarchical indices to columns?

Comment: this is what ``.unstack()`` does

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried, but it did not work. I've amended the question above to reflect this.